# knex.js: incorporating validation rules in create, update, and delete queries

Tags: javascript, validation, knex.js

Is it possible to incorporate data validation rules for Create, Update, and Delete operations when using the Knex.js query builder library, even though Knex does not do this [out of the box](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/772)?

If yes, then:

- is it a good idea or bad idea to stay inside Knex for this?
- if it is an OK approach, is there a decent example of this someone can point to?
- would you be better off and have less friction if you include Bookshelf.js?

Even Bookshelf does not come with a validation engine.

Answer (score 4):

It would be better to use bookshelf since it provides events during the transaction. While bookshelf doesn't come with a built in validation engine, you can use [Checkit](https://github.com/tgriesser/checkit). It is built by the same author of Knex and Bookshelf. By hooking into the `saving` event, you can effectively validate your model.

Here's a simple example:

```
var User = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('saving', this.validate, this);
    },
    validations: {
        email: ['required', 'validEmail'],
        username: ['required', 'alphaNumeric'],
        age: ['isNumeric']
    },
    validate: function(model, attrs, options) {
        return CheckIt(this.toJSON()).run(this.validations);
    }
});
```

Check out this [issue thread](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/39) on GH for more insight.